# NODE_ENV=production node index.js

Tags: npm, environment-variables

How can I fixed this problem ?

I also try `set NODE_ENV=something node index.js` this way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to execute 2 commands without splitting them, to execute 2 commands on one line in powershell you should use the `;` character in between like this:

```
set NODE_ENV=production; node index.js
```